# How do I play DVDs in Debian Jessie (i.e. libdvdcss)?

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

How do I install libdvdcss in Debian Jessie?

It seems that http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ is warned against.

https://wiki.debian.org/CDDVD lists three methods.

Can anyone tell me the pros and cons of each?

And why does it sometimes seem to be called libdvdcss and sometimes libdvdcss2?

Answer (score 6):

Well, I decided to take a punt on installing it direct from VideoLAN

edit /etc/apt/sources.list
and add the line:

```
deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /
```

Then add their key:

```
wget -O - http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc|sudo apt-key add -
```

Now update the system

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install libdvdcss2

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

And suddenly all dvd players start working on all dvds. Cool!

Comment: I'd suggest using https to download the key, and possibly with the repository (in which case you need the package apt-transport-https). Also, the signature on the packages cannot be checked because of https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Apt/Sha1Removal.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use debian repository you could simply add contrib packages like this in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib
```

Comment: Although it works (tested on stretch), it installs a LOT of dependencies (c++ compiler, perl libraries, etc.).